# how to solve this problem when I run the spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot

Currently I'm doing a read excel file in spring boot. But I unable to run the project because of the error that show at below. Anyone know how to solve this issue?
Here is the dependencies.

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
              <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
              <version>4.2.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
             <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
             <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-infrastructure</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.kumarpankaj18</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-excel</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    
    </dependencies>
```

Here is the exception.
[image]

Comment: I hope this helps, Please try it
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65046056/spring-boot-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-core-metrics-applications