# Spring Security Taglibs

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jsp-tags

I want to use spring security taglibs in my jsp (view), so I've made ​​the following changes to the project:

Pom.xml=>

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-json</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

I added the following prefix to my JSP =>

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
```

Then I use this in my JSP =>

```
    <sec:authorize access="!isAuthenticated()">Login</sec:authorize>
    <sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">Logout</sec:authorize>
```

Then when I try to run its show me these [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YC89V.png)

NB: Login and logout are working perfectly, but when I try to add spring-security-taglibs dependence in pom.xml this is when the problem occurs. I don't know what I should do.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/65046296/643500

Comment: it doesnt work for me already test it but it show me these errors
https://ibb.co/tZgtvTw

Comment: What did you exactly change?  Show the complete pom.  Add the errors as text not images in the original question