# ApplicationStartup error on Springboot app

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am converting a jboss app to Springboot application. I added all the spring boot dependencies in the pom file. The application is building fine with no error. But when i run the Springboot app locally in intellij, i am getting the below error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/metrics/ApplicationStartup
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:253)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:266)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332)
    at com.americanexpress.starhub.common.config.StarhubGrdApplication.main(StarhubGrdApplication.java:30)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.metrics.ApplicationStartup
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 5 more
```

Here is my main starter class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource({
  "classpath:cassandra-connection-ipc1-e0.properties",
  "classpath:appCrypto-${spring.profiles.active}.properties",
  "classpath:dataload_${spring.profiles.active}.properties"
})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.company.app")
@ImportResource("classpath:springbatch-context.xml")
public class SGApplication {
  private static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SGApplication.class);
  private static ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SGApplication.class, args);
    Runnable command =
        () ->
            LOGGER.info(
                "SGApplication app is up and running {}", System.currentTimeMillis());

    scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(command, 5, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
  }
}
```

I have below dependencies in my pom file.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.9</version>
        </dependency>
```

Any inputs on how to fix this?

Adding the whole pom file in here

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<properties>
    <start-class>com.americanexpress.starhub.common.config.StarhubGrdApplication</start-class>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.aexp.starhub</groupId>
    <artifactId>starhub-parent-pom</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>starhub-grd</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>starhub-grd</name>
<description>starhub grd</description>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.21.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>${cassandra.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.6</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-batch-infrastructure</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.54</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
        <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
        <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.fabric3.api</groupId>
        <artifactId>commonj</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.americanexpress.util.jconfig</groupId>
        <artifactId>jconfig</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-batch-admin-manager</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aexp.sec.crypto</groupId>
        <artifactId>ssaascrypto</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jutil_lang</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            </exclusion>               
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>            
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>au.com.bytecode</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>backport-util-concurrent</groupId>
        <artifactId>backport-util-concurrent-java12</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.0.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.americanexpress.ea</groupId>
        <artifactId>elf-log4j2-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.americanexpress.ea</groupId>
        <artifactId>elf-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.20</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>starhub-grd</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <warName>${project.artifactId}</warName>
                <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                <archive>
                    <manifestFile>src/main/webapp/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>false</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.7.201606060606</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptor>src/assembly/bin.xml</descriptor>
                <finalName>starhub-grd</finalName>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>false</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                        <goal>build-info</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
                <includeSystemScope>true</includeSystemScope>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                <version>1.0</version>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>test-compile</goal>
                                    <goal>compile</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </pluginExecutionFilter>
                            <action>
                                <execute />
                            </action>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                        <pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                                <version>1.0</version>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>install-file</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </pluginExecutionFilter>
                            <action>
                                <execute>
                                    <runOnIncremental>false</runOnIncremental>
                                </execute>
                            </action>
                        </pluginExecution>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Comment: Looking at your pom file I would recommend starting over from the very minimal and adding as needed. Right now you have many dependencies that are already included in the spring-boot collections or you are mixing matching spring-boot with spring dependencies. Another thing that I would recommend is moving out from the XML configuration (mostly spring) to use just the either configuration properties or `@configuration` class. Since you mention that this is a new project it will be good to start it with a very good concise set of dependencies for spring boot alone.

Comment: Did you research for the error `NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/metrics/ApplicationStartup` ? For example [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65046056/spring-boot-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-core-metrics-applications) or [related Spring issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/24880). Do those solutions help?

Comment: I tried those. unfortunately those did not work for my case.

Comment: What is this class `StarhubGrdApplication`