# SPRING BOOT UPGRADE CAUSES ISSUE WHILE STARTING UP

Tags: spring-boot, startup

I'm trying to upgrade spring boot version to 2.6.6 from 2.2.x, I got

> ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.metrics.ApplicationStartup.

The pom.xml below:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
        <relativePath/>
</parent>
```

> <  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: > >
> org/springframework/core/metrics/ApplicationStartup at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.(SpringApplication.java:228)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.(SpringApplication.java:241)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301)
> at
> com.sams.clubops.receiptcheck.transactionaudit.AuditApplication.main(AuditApplication.java:19)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> org.springframework.core.metrics.ApplicationStartup at
> java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) at
> sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352) at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ... 5 more

I don't know if there any conflict with this version. I wanna get some help, thanks.

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65046056/spring-boot-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-core-metrics-applications)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the version changed if you use SpringToolSuite4, forcing the Update Maven Project should work: Project > Update Maven Project > Force Update of Snapshots/Releases

Comment: tried already , i still get the error

Comment: What version of java do you use?

Comment: i use 1.8 version

Comment: worked after resolving the conflicting dependencies and updating the dependency management