# Spring gateway server won't start - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/metrics/ApplicationStartup

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm trying to learn about Spring Gateway (how it is put together, how it works).

I'm following [this tutorial here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway), and I run into an issue as I try to run the server. I haven't even done anything specific yet, outside of what this tutorial shows.

There is no mention of that issue on it, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65046056/spring-boot-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-core-metrics-applications) didn't help my case.

I'm not sure what I'm missing as the issue I'm running into didn't seem to be common.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my pom.xml :

```xml
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <groupId>com.container</groupId>
        <artifactId>gateway</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>gateway</name>
        <description>Gateway</description>
        <properties>
            <java.version>11</java.version>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
                <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    
        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-gateway</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.0.RC2</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>
    
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
            <finalName>gateway-app</finalName>
        </build>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>spring-milestones</id>
                <name>Spring Milestones</name>
                <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>spring-snapshots</id>
                <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
                <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </releases>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>spring-milestones</id>
                <name>Spring Milestones</name>
                <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>spring-snapshots</id>
                <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
                <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </releases>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
    
    </project>
```

Comment: You have some dependencies mismatch. Any specific reason for using very old release candidate version of `spring-cloud-gateway` 2.0.0.RC2? If you are learning better use the latest stable version. Spring Initializr https://start.spring.io/ could be a good start.

Comment: @Alex Like I said, I just followed the tutorial, which is fairly recent (July 2022). I didn't know they had not updated that version in a while. Anyway, your comment did help solve my problem, but now for a very different reason, my server starts and then crashes (different error log this time)

Comment: Please update the question and provide more details